# Replace simple HTML elements through complex

Tags: javascript, html, element

Simple elements should be replaced by complex elements that are located in a library (other file).

I have tried a lot, but unfortunately nothing works..

---

Simple element:

```
<div class="image" data-src="http://www.example.com/picture.jpg"></div>
```

Complexe element:

```
<div>
    <p>Whats going on?!</p>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/picture.jpg">
</div>
```

---

This I have tried:

index.html:

```
<a href="#" id="btnLoad">Load</a>
<div class="container" data-href="http://www.example.com/"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // .load()
    $("#btnLoad").click(function(){ 
        $('.container').load('/ajax/content.html'); 

        var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
        for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) 
        {
            var mysrc = elms[i].getAttribute("data-href");
            elms[i].children[0].setAttribute("src", mysrc);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

content.html:

```
<iframe src="" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></iframe>
```

---

Thank you and best regards,
NoPlan__

Comment: Share your (failed) approaches please, and we will support you with fixing them.

Comment: I have just done ;)

Comment: Could you try to explain further, in more detail what the code should do, and what it is currently incorrectly doing. Is there any error logging?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var url = img.getAttribute("data-href");
var new_div = document.createElement("div");
new_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery way to do it. You need the `.replaceWith` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = $("#image").attr("data-href");
  $('#image').replaceWith('<div><p>Whats going on?!</p><img src=' + url + '/></div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image" data-href="http://www.example.com/picture.jpg">Hello</div>
```

Comment: This seems the right way.But i need to load the complex element from another file.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="image" data-href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png"></div>
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Make It So">
```

You can achieve your desired result with the following:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  var div = $('#image');
  var newDiv = div.clone();
  var p = $('<p>');
  p.text('Hello World!');
  newDiv.append(p);
  var img = $('<img>');
  img.attr("src", div.data('href'));
  newDiv.append(img);
  div.after(newDiv);
  div.remove();
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/mmyx1r8q/1/).

Explanation:

The approach I took was to clone the original div, modify the clone and add the new elements to it, add the clone to the DOM and remove the original div.  You could just modify the original div and skip the cloning.

Comment: unfortunately I have to load the complex element from another file. This prepares headache for me.

Comment: @NoPlan__ - if you want an answer that works for you, you need to ask a question that includes the relevant information.  I have no way of knowing what your file content looks like, nor how you determine which content in the file should be chosen to replace your target.  You gave us an example and my answer addresses that example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you ended up with such a requirement but below is one easy way to do it

**If you are using jQuery** - this is readily available - see https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

For your example

`$("#image").replaceWith("<div>.....</div>")`

**or with plain javascript:**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("image");
elem.removeAttribute("data-href")
elem.innerHTML = "<p>.....</p><img..../>"
```